# Why is the <html> element doesn't fill the window?

Tags: html, css

I am writing a website and am having an odd problem.

```css
#Text {
    margin-left:15vw;
    width:70vw;
    background-color:white;
    opacity:0.8;
    vertical-align:center;
}
body {
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>SomeTitle</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <img src="someUnimportantImage.jpg" height="100vh">
  <div id="text">
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>More text</p>
    <p>Even more text</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

My problem is that when I load my page in google chrome (I haven't tried other browsers),

1. there is a mysterious white space at the top that I can't get rid of
2. the `<html>` element doesn't fill the browers height, and therefore
3. setting the images `height="100vh"` makes it fill the `<html>` element, but not the page.

What I need is for `<html>` to fill the page and for the white space at the top to disappear.

**EDIT**

I got the whitespace to disapear by using the code at meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset.

Comment: To help prevent little cross-browser errors like this, it's best to use a CSS reset. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use viewport units, you don't need to worry about the height/width of the `<html>` element. However you should move the inline `height="100vh"` into the CSS instead. And I don't see any "mysterious white space at the top" since you already set `body{margin:0;}`, it might be caused by your other styles if you still see it.

```
img {
    height:100vh;
}
```

And be aware, CSS class/id names are case sensitive, `#Text` and `#text` are not the same.

```css
body {
    margin:0;
}
img {
    height:100vh;
}
#text {
    margin-left:15vw;
    width:70vw;
    background-color:white;
    opacity:0.8;
    vertical-align:center;
}
```

```html
<img src="//dummyimage.com/500">
<div id="text">
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>More text</p>
    <p>Even more text</p>
</div>
```

**Edit:** The white space might be from the `<p>` tag, as it has some default top and bottom `margin` from the browser.